# Excel 2007 Visual Basic Editor: eats spaces, throws cursor around

Tags: excel, vba

I can't resolve this issue, I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164138/vba-editor-auto-deletes-spaces-at-the-ends-of-lines) but:

- setting the workbook to Manual calculation (alt-m-x-m or alt-t-o>formulas) didn't work
- Setting editor options to disable: Auto syntax check & Background compile didn't work

anybody have any idea how to fix this very annoying behaviour, I'm used to quickly pop up VBA (alt-f11), f7 to get into code and write some quick procedures there... and it's hard to get out of that habit, I don't want to write any office extension to just add a single quote to every cell in the range

```
For Each rg In Selection
  rg = chr(39) & rg.value
Next
```

F5, done...

Comment: I'm using Vista and just tested on my colleagues laptop running windowsXP. It works fine there (even with auto calculation & auto syntax on). I'll try restarting, then re-installing if it's still not fixed 'n let you know

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had this exact problem and the following worked for me.

1.Click the Microsoft Office Button, and then click Excel Options

2.Click the Add-Ins category

3.In the Manage box, click COM Add-ins, and then click Go.

4.Look for an add in called 'Load Test Report AddIn' then uncheck it

5.restart excel

This addin is installed with VS2010 Beta2

Answer (score 2):

I'm using excel 2010 and face similar problem.  When I hit space bar, editor removes the space and put cursor to end of last character.  Tried unchecking add-in coms without resolution.

"In Excel 2010, toggling Design Mode button on the Developer Ribbon Tab solves the problem for me."

Or in vba editor, CLICK on Design Mode button (icon with pencil) to enter design mode.  From the Run menu, select "Design Mode".

Got it from this link:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/3353f2d3-7e92-424b-934c-0eedd21b9a90/excel-2010-vb-editor-auto-deleting-spaces?forum=exceldev

Answer (score 1):

Winword VBA IDE works fine, so it's only in Excel for the moment.

I have tried re-installing, I have tried the Excel options > Resources > diagnostic tool which reported that it fixed 1 issue but the problem remained.

The problem effectively seems to be that the Visual Basic Editor compiles every second (or less) and removes spaces.

An ugly work around is to put a single quote after your cursor and it won't remove the spaces, but that's just silly.

I'm currently waiting for the Office 2007 Enterprise "Change" > "Repair" to finish & test it again, else I'm going to stick with the single quote.

Comment: Repair didn't fix it, I just wrote 40+ lines using a single quote to trick the compiler & I'm going to stick with that 'till I install win7 and get rid of all this. Unfortunetaly due to company policy & as I'm about to go on-site for a project I can't do it right now :(

Answer (score 1):

I've hit this issue too, and for me it was related to an Excel add-in which would explain why you're not seeing it in the Word VBE. Try going into the trust center and disabling all application add-ins - if that fixes it, then you can work out which is going wrong by a process of elimination. In my case, it was the Load Test Report Addin which installs with VS2010 beta 2.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem recently with Excel 2010. Toggling Design mode didn't work and I didn't have the 'Load Test Report Add-In'. However, I had a couple of other Add-Ins and it was one of those (Jive for Office) that was causing the issue.

So in 2010 you should go to File>Options>Add-Ins. At the bottom of the dialog box in 'Manage' select 'COM Add-Ins' and click Go. See what's in there and unselect each in turn. For me, the result was instant - I didn't even have to restart Excel.