# Cursor movement while writing VBA code

Tags: excel, vba

I am facing a very frustrating situation where I'm writing some VBA code in excel and the cursor keeps shifting a space to the left for ever word i write.
I just cant seem to control it. As I keep writing code cursor keeps moving 1 space backwards and it all becomes a long word. and I have to manually go to the code and seperate the code with a space.

Is this a bug in MS Excel 2010 and is there any fix for this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1204467/293078 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/1164138/293078 might help.  Or http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showthread.php?395421-Annoying-Autocorrect-in-Excel-2007-VBA-IDE.  You aren't losing your mind!

Answer (score 3):

OK, I have found the answer.

1.Click the Microsoft Office Button, and then click Excel Options
2.Click the Add-Ins category
3.In the Manage box, click COM Add-ins, and then click Go.
4.Look for an add in called 'Load Test Report AddIn' then uncheck it
5.restart excel
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2552264/475709

Answer (score 0):

I am having this problem on Excel 365 for Mac (v16.54).

I found that turning off AutoSave was the solution. Thanks to redOctober13 in another thread for alerting me to the solution.
[VBA editor auto-deletes spaces at the ends of lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164138/vba-editor-auto-deletes-spaces-at-the-ends-of-lines?answertab=active#tab-top)