# How do I turn off autocorrect in VBA in Excel 2007?

Tags: excel, vba

My VBA in Excel 2007 is going crazy and it's automatically moving my cursor all over the place. Is this supposed to be happening? Is there some way to turn this off?

Comment: Here are some more details....
If I type Dim, then hit the space bar and wait about 1 second, Excel is moving my cursor back to the end of Dim, in effect deleting my space. then when i start typing its a mistake.

Comment: I don't think this is related to autocorrect, as I have autocorrect turned on and have never seen the behaviour you describe. Can you give more details? Is it only Excel that has this behaviour? Do you get similar results if you are in an Excel workbook?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this:

[VBA editor auto-deletes spaces at the ends of lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164138/vba-editor-auto-deletes-spaces-at-the-ends-of-lines)

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't describing my problem properly, so I never saw that question. You've save me immense amounts of aggravation.