# VBA monitor folder for new files

Tags: vba, excel, vb6

So I'm trying to write a VBA program that will monitor a folder for new files and then do stuff with them. I've found some promising examples on using the WMI api:

[Receive notification of file creation in VBA without polling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18242252/receive-notification-of-file-creation-in-vba-without-polling)

http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/211547-monitor-new-files-folder.html

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2004/10/11/how-can-i-automatically-run-a-script-any-time-a-file-is-added-to-a-folder/

But here's the thing: It seems like the tack everyone takes with these examples is to wire the VBA into an Excel spreadsheet as a macro. People treat Excel as a poor-man's programming environment. Fair enough. The problem is, I need this to run when the user is closed out out this magic excel file with the macro.

Something tells me I need to make a full windows application in visual studio with VB6.0 or C# and run the application in the background as some kind of a scheduled task. Is that the right path to take or is there something simple that I'm missing in these Excel/VBA tutorials?

(Apologies for the generality of the question. I know that the community appreciates specific questions.)

Comment: *Is* Excel something else than a poor man's programming environment?

Comment: You do understand that VBA stands for *Visual Basic for Applications*, and that it only works within the confines of one of the applications that are part of MS Office? And that therefore the code **has to run** in one of those applications? And that VBA cannot run outside an Excel spreadsheet or a Word document or <insert all the other Office applications here>? And that therefore you cannot use it for a stand alone program? VBA is the *poor man's programming language for Office Applications*.

Comment: Yes, I get that. My instincts are to avoid VBA all together, but a client loves it, and therefore I need a solid answer for when they ask me "Why didn't you make a macro for excel to do this?" And now I have it.

Comment: a) [vbscript] run through the Windows' O/S event scheduler should be enough to do this. At least enough to monitor the folder. [vba] can do the rest once the [vbscript] launches the appropriate workbook or [vbscript] can do everything. b) While VBA is an entry level language which often starts with an office worker discovering the 'macro' recorder, good VBA code is anything but entry level. Whether you are planning to use [c#] or [vb.net], at some point you will have to load a library that allows you to do thin that are native to [vba] within the Excel application object.

Comment: A simple alternative to "make a full windows application in visual studio with VB6.0 or C#" is to write a Windows level script in visual basic with extension *.vbs. But that's if this can be done in a simple script. You can write vbs scripts using any text editor, I use Notepad++.

Answer (score 4):

VBA and VBScript is similar. For WMI pretty much the same. Here are three scripts. You can also wire up WMI with event handlers so you can have multiple events rather than one as shown here.

VB6 is VBA that can be compiled into an exe. VB6 hosts the VBA language as does Office.

**InstanceCreationEvent**

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")
Set colMonitoredEvents = objWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery _
("SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 10 WHERE Targetinstance ISA 'CIM_DirectoryContainsFile' and TargetInstance.GroupComponent= 'Win32_Directory.Name=""c:\\\\scripts""'")
Do
    Set objLatestEvent = colMonitoredEvents.NextEvent
    Wscript.Echo objLatestEvent.TargetInstance.PartComponent
Loop
```

**InstanceModificationEvent**

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")
Set colMonitoredEvents = objWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery _
("SELECT * FROM __InstanceModificationEvent WITHIN 10 WHERE Targetinstance ISA 'CIM_DirectoryContainsFile' and TargetInstance.GroupComponent= 'Win32_Directory.Name=""c:\\\\scripts""'")
Do
    Set objLatestEvent = colMonitoredEvents.NextEvent
    Wscript.Echo objLatestEvent.TargetInstance.PartComponent
Loop
```

**InstanceDeletionEvent**

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")
Set colMonitoredEvents = objWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery _
("SELECT * FROM __InstanceDeletionEvent WITHIN 10 WHERE Targetinstance ISA 'CIM_DirectoryContainsFile' and TargetInstance.GroupComponent= 'Win32_Directory.Name=""c:\\\\scripts""'")
Do
    Set objLatestEvent = colMonitoredEvents.NextEvent
    Wscript.Echo objLatestEvent.TargetInstance.PartComponent
Loop
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Excel is a good solution for this kind of need.  What about using VB.NET to do the work?

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/150149-using-filesystemwatcher-in-vbnet/

Yes, it's overkill, but if you get into it, you'll find all kinds of other really cool things that you can do with VB.NET.  I love working with Excel, but I'm really a huge proponent of using the right tool for the job.

Comment: I couldn't agree more. But it's for a client. And the client absolutely has to have it in a macro, because of reasons. I've tried to talk them out of it, but they're just dead-set on doing this as an excel macro.

Answer (score 0):

Ok- I found a solution for this. It's not pretty, but you can copy the blurb of code found at this tutorial:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383665(v=VS.85).aspx

into an excel macro and it will work almost without modification, scheduling a task which will occur even after excel has closed down. The solution is to use VBA to grab an instance of the task scheduler

```
Set service = CreateObject("Schedule.Service")
call service.Connect()
```

And then perform all of the verbose configurations on that object to schedule the task. From there it's only a skip hop and a jump to write an other macro that will actually do the deed on the folder.