# Catching "move to explorer" event from Outlook

Tags: vba, windows, outlook

Recently I have written small tool (vb.net WinForms) for our company that creates structure and archives all Emails that are in x, y Folder in Outlook. This tool then renames and converts these .msg files to .eml files.

Now it would be perfect, if these Emails would automatically convert themself when user places it directly in the destination in Windows-Explorer folder per Drag and Drop. For that I assume I would have to run script/programm whenever Event X (moving Email from Outlook to explorer) occurs.

Has anyone an idea if catching that event would be possible? Or maybe any better ideas? I thought of some scripts that run on server and check for new files (once daily for example), but the first solution is more appearing to me.

Comment: Difficult to monitor windows explorer directly without a dedicated monitoring program as per Eugene's answer. You could potentially utilise a timer within Outlook to either look for alterations to the contents of the folder (or maybe check created date/last accessed date or some other date if drag/drop assigns it at the time) then prod your tool to do it's job. Otherwise maybe a vbscript and task scheduler combo...

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the `Items.ItemAdd` event on the folder to track and convert new items.

Comment: The `ItemAdd` event is fired when an item is moved to an Outlook folder, not Windows.

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide any events when items are saved to a folder by dragging and dropping items. You can use a file system watcher to track folder changes, see [VBA monitor folder for new files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36903022/vba-monitor-folder-for-new-files) for more information.