# Excel VBA snapping back my space bar action

Tags: vba, excel, comments

This is a weird question, but I could not formulate the question properly in Google.

When I write comments in Excel-VBA, it for some reason snaps back my cursor on all space bar hits.

Example:

```
Dim Arr() As String 'This is |<-- When I hit the space bar, I expect the cursor to be here.
```

But if I am not quick enough, it snaps it back to `'This is|<-- Here`

This is really bothering me because I have to constantly go back and forth in putting spaces in my lines of text that are space-less.

Some behavior:
When type really fast, I think I am able to overshoot(?) the replacement, and it doesn't snap it back, but if I go slowly, it is faster than me. Also, if I hit space, it snaps back, I hit space, it moves the cursor, and now only after a 0.5 second delay it snaps it back again.

I have Excel 2010.

Anyone else had the same issue, or know how to fix it? It isn't a big thing, it is just annoying.

Comment: this seems to happen to people seemingly at random. try clicking the design mode button on the toolbar

Comment: We experienced this in my computer classes. Switch to the Developer tab, COM Add-Ins.
There are several options by default on some systems- list the options for me. One of those is the culprit and I'll recognize the name of the one that's causing the problem.

Comment: It sounds like this is the same problem as:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164138/vba-editor-auto-deletes-spaces-at-the-ends-of-lines

Comment: @Wally, yes, and I think the correct answer is ade's, i.e., the one about disabling the "Load Test Report" addin.

Comment: Had this happen to me a few weeks ago in Powerpoint VBE. Not sure what I did to resolve it, other than just a reboot I think.

Comment: I think it has something to do with the autosave option. In my case I switched autosave off, and then saved the spreadsheet and it's started working properly now...

Comment: Apparently this issue is the "AUTOSAVE" that is activated automatically when you are working on an excel file located on a ONEDRIVE directory. **Turning autosave "off" is a way to solve it**. Please check (https://stackoverflow.com/a/54081415/2843348) as it is very simular issue (the spacerbar not working well on VBA editor).

Answer (score 6):

This likely wasn't the original issue, but for anyone else with this incredibly frustrating problem who also happens to use OneDrive - my problem was simply that a workbook I had open while I was editing VBA in my PERSONAL.XLSB was stored in a OneDrive directory. Once I moved it out of OneDrive, I stopped having the issue.

To determine this, I found that one particular workbook was causing the issue once the other answers didn't work for me, so I copied just the sheet I needed to a new workbook and saved. When this didn't work, I copied values+formatting to a new workbook and saved. When *that* didn't work, I copied just values to a new workbook and saved. Then, when I was just about to pull out what little remaining hair I have left, I copied the original offending file out of my OneDrive directory. And...voila.

Comment: Thanks! You have made my day and helped me in keeping my sanity

Answer (score 4):

Turn on design mode in the developer tab.

Comment: Yes! This worked for me. Can you explain why though?

Comment: My guess is that it's trying to run/parse the script and design mode turns that off.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Tools Menu -> Options -> Editor Tab

Clear the Auto Syntax Check box