# Spacebar not working at end of the line in Excel VBA Editor

Tags: excel, vba, vbe

I moved my personal.xlsb to my new laptop and I am having a strange issue.

1. The spacebar is not working at the end of the line except it's a totally empty line.

> Example 1 : Not working example | Not working

[image: example1]

> Example 2 : Working example | Would work

[image: example2]

2. When I was pressing the spacebar, the text select pointer didn't move, but the position indicator is blinking between the original position and (col+1).

> Pointer position indicator image

[image: pointer position indicator image]

Comment: BTW: I didn't create any timer events. I tried design mode, not working, I tried to turn on and off the auto syntax check, not working.

Comment: All my vba codes are in persional.xlsb and I found a rediculous thing: if I opened a file from Onedrive, the issue happened and the issue would be gone if I open a file from my local.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue.  I found if I turned off AutoSave, it worked fine.  If I opened a new workbook that had AutoSave turned on, the issue would come back until I turned off AutoSave.[AutoSave toggle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZJv1.png)

Comment: Worked for me Thanks

Comment: 4.5 years later this error and fortunately also the workaround still exist (at least in Excel on Mac)

Answer (score 1):

So I had this exact same problem on my Personal Workbook. I found that if I create another module in the active workbook, for whatever reason it fixes the error.

FYI, for some reason, I have to then save the active workbook as a macro-enabled workbook and then if I open another workbook the problem doesn't persist.