# vba intellisense very annoying behavior

Tags: vba, ms-access, intellisense

Sometimes,  I could not pinpoint the cause of this behavior, but VBA intellisense on excel or access starts acting really fast/weird. 
Examples :
I type a space and it removes it in the next 0.2 sec if I don't type anything, If i want to prevent mycodelookinglikethis I need to think of the next letter to type and do it quickly or manually add space afterward.
If I do ctrl-space to see object methods or properties, it only shows for about 2 seconds then the box disappear, I can't scroll down at all.

I tried to go in tools >> Option >> Editor and uncheck everything, yet the behavior stays, I can't seem to find a way to stop or restart intellisense.

I don't have privileges to install programs on my computer. This problem doesn't happen all the time and a reboot doesn't fix it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164138/vba-editor-auto-deletes-spaces-at-the-ends-of-lines

Comment: Another remedy is to go to the `Run` menu in Access and toggle on `design mode`, which temporarily cancels this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Access or Excel has some Form whose timer events are running in the background. When a timer event is running, which means the code (even though not in the same module) will also be making a quick run. To see if this is the case, open the form with SHIFT bypass. Then close all objects in the main window. Then try adding some code, you should be able to see the intellisense long enough to choose or browse.

So identify which form or event is making this 0.2 second loop. Fixing that would fix your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this problem recently using VBA in Powerpoint.  The behaviour had started unexpectedly as I hadn't installed anything nor developed a hidden form.  I persevered but only have 2 seconds to look finally drove me to reboot.  When I did I was informed that Skype had a new release.  I postponed such and Skype booted up.

Returning to my code, Intellisense continued to misbehave, closing too quickly for me to explore objects.  As I knew it had to be a timer and the only timer I saw recently was Skype, I wondered if it was the Skype update.  So I shut down Skype completely and "voila," Intellisense returned to behaving normally.

Note. A short while later, the annoying behaviour resumed even though Skype was closed.  I restarted Skype, installed the update.  And now, no problem.

Answer (score 0):

For Access, it could be due to timers in your forms.  Once you disable the timers, the intellisense will not disappear no more.  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

For me it is the form timer event. When I commented out the timer event handler code it work as before.